# When I run my project on jenkins it seems to login to ssh using my other officemate account then it closes and never read my test cases

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

When I run my project on jenkins it seems to login to ssh using my other officemate account then it closes and never read my test cases. She don't have access to my computer because we do not share station and we are working from home. I can also confirm that I'm calling the correct file for the test cases. Can someone advise me of what's happening and how can I resolve this? Also, I'm using robot framework. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Better if you also share the jenkinsfile or job configuration. It's probably using your colleague's credentials in the job config.

Comment: It's a newly created job and test file and I created them so I can confirm that it's not using the colleague's credentials in the job config and jenkins file.

Comment: The documentation of the library says that the command is "Login   user   password" but in that screenshot you have "Login   user, password".
Is it just a printout error or you have it like that? because that may explain what you are seeing in the logs
If not, I would Log the variables and see what is being sent because that "login" command is very simple

Comment: no, it's not my issue.. that ssh library call for login is not part of my test cases.. I don't know why it's there when I ran build